# onCheckboxClicked in Fragment

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick, fragment

I've been working on this error for too many hours now. The frustrating thing is that the code doesn't have any errors, but when I'm trying to launch the application it doesn't work. And when I delete the code I'm working on, the application runs perfect..

Is there anything missing in the code? Do I have any unnecessary code?

I'm very thankful for any help!

This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;


 public class FörstängningFragment extends Fragment {


    int checkOne = '0';
    int checkTwo = '0';
    int checkThree = '0';
    ImageView bild = (ImageView)
            getView().findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forstangning, container, false);
        bild = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);
        bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxbak);
        CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        bild = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);


        c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checkOne = '1';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    checkOne = '0';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
                }
            }
        });
        c2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checkTwo = '1';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    checkTwo = '0';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
                }
            }
        });
        c3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checkThree = '1';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    checkThree = '0';
                    bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My logcat says:

```
01-21 20:56:31.869    1349-1349/hej.swipeview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hej.swipeview.FörstängningFragment.<init>(FörstängningFragment.java:20)
        at hej.swipeview.FragmentPageAdapter.getItem(FragmentPageAdapter.java:25)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show us your logs...

Answer (score 0):

locate the `forstangningimage` view after `onCreateView` is called, (not when the java object is created)

```
public class FörstängningFragment extends Fragment {


    int checkOne = '0';
    int checkTwo = '0';
    int checkThree = '0';
    ImageView bild;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forstangning, container, false);
        bild = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);
        bild.setImageResource(R.drawable.forstangning);
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxbak);
        CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        bild = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forstangningimage);
```

Also, Dont use a `View.OnClickListener`,  instead migrate to using the [`CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) which is better suited for your needs.

As [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) inherits from [`CompoundButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html), an [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html#ClickListener) would be

```
CheckBox c = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxbak);
....
c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

And then repeat for `c2` and `c3`

Comment: I updated my answer so the fragment will not try to locate the `forstangningimage` view until after `onCreateView` is called

Comment: The code is still green, but the launcher doesn't do as I want. I've updated my code so you can see how it looks like at the moment.

Comment: Maybe I have to add something in my ActivitySwipe or my FragmentPageAdapter to get the code in my Fragment to work?

Comment: I've updated what my logcat says. No, it seems to me like it's the same problem. It is like it was before.